# Мобильное приложение для iOS и Android

Tags: javascript, php, android, ios

Нужно сделать приложение такого типа:

вопрос/варианты ответов, пользователю нужно отвечать на вопросы. В результате кол правильных ответов. + график истории правильных и неправильных ответов.

Вопросы и варианты ответов, нужно дать возможность админу добавлять удалять..

Я веб-разработчик. Разработкой моб. приложений никогда не занимался. 
Хотел бы понять, какие есть популярные системы, чтобы разработать Мобильное приложение для iOS и Android используя html, javascript и php ?

Далее приложение нужно разместить на play market и app store.

Comment: Если html, почему бы не просто написать веб-сайт?

Comment: Приложение пишешь на React Native сразу будет компилироваться и под IOS и под Android а серверную часть на php можешь написать, получается приложение просто делает запросы можно http к серверу а там php обрабатывает как нужно и возвращает ответ приложению

Comment: Получается приложение будет работать только если есть инет на мобилке?

И можно ли через react native не используя нативные языки, использовать какие-то хранилище? БД?  Где мне нужно будет хранить вопросы и ответы?

Comment: @234234234, забей, ты же не за плюсами и минусами пришел, а за ответами. То, что ты собираешься сделать, если это вообще возможно, скорее всего будет сплошь из костылей. Если решил разрабатывать приложения под смартфоны не лучше ли потратить время, чтобы изучить более подходящие инструменты. А то, что ты сделаешь никто не сможешь дорабатывать, в резюме ты это не добавишь и новые инструменты ты использовать не сможешь. -имхо:)

Comment: @234234234 конечно не будет работать без интернета если только данные будут в кеше, ни каких БД в мобильных приложениях нет если понимать под БД то что понимают в веб а это скорее СУБД, сами подумайте если у вас будет БД на стороне клиента как будут обновляться данные от пользователя к пользователю ? и если база будет большая ваше приложение будет весить гигабайты и зачем нужно такое приложение на телефоне не понятно

Comment: А где тогда мне хранить базу с вопросами и вариантами ответов?

Comment: @ИгорьБраницкий бред не говорите, насчет СУБД в мобильных приложениях? А как же SQLite, Room. Данные можно получить от любого сервера, на котором лежит другая СУБД и сохранять во встроенной СУБД на мобильном смартфоне, что позволяет использовать данные и в оффлайне

Answer (score 0):

Из html страницы собрать iOS/Android приложение можно с помощью https://phonegap.com/, для самих опросов и хранения ответов можно посмотреть на Google Forms (возможно и хватит функционала для конкретной задачи)